# Autocomplete React this.props in WebStorm

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, webstorm

Is there a way to make WebStorm to autocomplete my custom props that has been passed down to `this.props` and defined in `static propTypes = {}` and to understand their proper type. So if I have property
`items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape(myCustomShape)),` in `this.props.items[0].` after the dot to receive all of the properties of `myCustomShape`.

I have managed to some kind bypass that by using JSDocs `@typedef myCustomShape` where a have defined `items: myCustomShape[],` and using `this.props` passed as parameter to a function and using `@param {myCustomShape} props`. So I will receive all of my properties that I need but then WebStorm complains when I call that function with `this.props` that is not assignable to that parameter. I really don't care much of that issue but I don't want to have any warnings.

I'm wondering if anybody came up with a solution to that (...stupid) issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is your bad not webstorm bad   change `static PropTypes = {}` by  `static propTypes = {}`  (lowercase not capital ) and lets see

Comment: I think its a bug in current version of WebStorm. I'm experiencing similar issue.

Comment: That is fixed in WebStorm 2016.3.6
Build #WS-163.15188.15, built on April 12, 2017